# write a scala method which returns Nothing

Tags: scala

-> How can we `write a scala method` whose return type is `Nothing`?

-> Do we `ever need to write such methods`? Are there any `useful scenarios`?

Answer (score 5):

You can't actually return a value of type `Nothing` because there are no values of type `Nothing`. So the only way to define a function with return type `Nothing` is to never return at all.

One example would be a function that just calls itself recursively infinitely. Another would be one that always throws an exception or simply exits the application (`sys.exit`'s return type is `Nothing`).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Nothing is used in functions which never returns or terminates abnormaly by throwing some exception 
eg:

```
scala> def funcReturnNothing : Nothing = throw new RuntimeException("runtime exception")
funcReturnNothing: Nothing
```

More explanation.
Functions in Scala are co-variant in its return type let's say return type of the function is `T` so this function can only return values which are subtype of `T` or type of `T` and `Nothing` is subtype of all other type (Lowest in type chain) So, in actual you can not return anything useful from it but exceptions throwing has a type `Nothing` which you can return.